# Newbie webscraping with python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

This is my first attempt to use web scraping in python to extract some links from a webpage.
This the webpage i am interested in getting some data from:

> http://www.hotstar.com/tv/bhojo-gobindo/14172/seasons/season-5

I am interest in extracting all the instance of following from above webpage:

> href="/tv/bhojo-gobindo/14172/gobinda-is-in-a-fix/1000196352"

I have written following regex to extract all the matches of above type of links:

```
r"href=\"(\/tv\/bhojo-gobindo\/14172\/.*\/\d{10})\""
```

Here is quick code i have written to try to extract all the regex mataches:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import re
  import requests

  url = "http://www.hotstar.com/tv/bhojo-gobindo/14172/seasons/season-5"

  page = requests.get(url)
  l = re.findall(r'href=\"(\/tv\/bhojo-gobindo\/14172\/.*\/\d{10})\"', page.text)
  print(l)
```

When I run the above code I get following ouput:

```
./links2.py  
[]
```

When I inspect the webpage using developer tools within the browser I can see this links but when I try to extract the text I am interested in(href="/tv/bhojo-gobindo/14172/gobinda-is-in-a-fix/1000196352") using python3 script I get no matches.

Am I downloading the webpage correctly, how do I make sure I am getting all of the webapage from within my script. i have a feeling I am missing parts of the web page when using the requests to get the web page.

Any help please.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Read: [Why is it a bad idea to use regex for scraping HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Comment: The data you want is dynamically generated with Javascript. It is not available in the page source (which is what the `requests.get(...)` returns).

Comment: Is there any way i can have generated saved as a text file on pc and then try extract the links? Is it possible to save the as a file using the browser.

Comment: You would probably need to use `selenium` with headless Chrome. See for example: https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python